# fzf refuses to execute in bind option when selection is a path

Tags: fzf

This is the test script:

```
zapit()
{
find ~/ -type d  | fzf --header='ENTER to select, ESC to abort' --bind='enter:execute(ls {})'
}
```

I had my own function call inside the *execute bracket*. But as the *execute* ignored it. I replaced my function by **ls {}** to check this out. This test should list the files in the selected directory. I get nothing at all.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with `echo test`? It works for me. I need `echo test; sleep 1` to see *how* it works, but it works.

Comment: echo test is not the issue. It is the script that won't run the echo command -- or any command for that matter.

Comment: Please [edit] and provide [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659), something we may use to replicate the problem. Since there is no problem with `echo test`, what you posted until now is not it.

Comment: `ls {}` works for me. Again, I need `ls {}; sleep 1` to see how it works, but it works. You say you get nothing at all. Please confirm the directory is not empty.

Comment: Edited with another example. The function must be defined first (even in terminal). Then typing zapit in terminal would run the function and should provide an answer.

Comment: You are right with sleep 1 it gives me a chance to see that it works. Now my own function is supposed to zip the files in that directory. I have not seen that zip file getting generated. I will check it with much longer sleep command to see the effect. Thanks.

Comment: All sorted, thanks to your **sleep 1** idea @KamilMaciorowski. I simply had to source my user-defined functions first inside the **execute** brackets. Thanks again.